# because user depends on both intl ^0.16.1 and horizontal_calendar_widget ^1.0.2, version solving failed

Tags: android, flutter

Because no versions of horizontal_calendar_widget match >1.0.2 <2.0.0 and horizontal_calendar_widget 1.0.2 depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk, horizontal_calendar_widget ^1.0.2 requires flutter_localizations any from sdk.
And because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0, horizontal_calendar_widget ^1.0.2 requires intl 0.17.0.
So, because user depends on both intl ^0.16.1 and horizontal_calendar_widget ^1.0.2, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1; So, because user depends on both intl ^0.16.1 and horizontal_calendar_widget ^1.0.2, version solving failed.)

Comment: Can you post your dependencies and dev_dependencies section of pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: please share screenshot of your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: added the screenshot .

Answer (score 2):

`intl ^0.17.0` is null safe whereas `horizontal_calendar_widget ^1.0.2` is not a null safe.

In case you have migrated your project to null safety, try using some other calendar widget as horizontal_calendar_widget ^1.0.2 has not released its null safety version yet. Else you can use intl 0.16.1.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your intl in pubspec.yaml to:

```
intl: ^0.17.0
```